# python curve fitting optimization GUI

Tags: user-interface, anaconda, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I'm new to programming but i have to do a project in python which is about to make a GUI for curve fitting. My inputs are the data points and the functions that should be fitted. The method of fitting is suggested to be chooseable for example least squares method or other fitting methods in the GUI. My problem is when i find some decent resource i get an error code when installing some packages that will be used. I use anaconda for python. My question is where should i start this project ? Could you guys suggest some decent resource for this kind of problem?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Looks like you need a lot of basic problems to solve first. Good thing is: using anaconda, you already obtained scipy. So all curve_fitting stuff is already there. Now you have to decide which GUI-lib to use and how to use scipy. There are tons of tutorials for both! Keep searching! This question is way too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I have several of these done with different GUI frameworks, all have curve fitting and surface fitting with plots of fitted curves and surfaces.  All have the same functionality, and should make a good example for a similar project.  My personal recommendation is tkinter.

```
https://github.com/zunzun/tkInterFit (tkinter)
https://github.com/zunzun/wxPythonFit (wxpython)
https://github.com/zunzun/pyQt5Fit (pyqt5)
https://github.com/zunzun/pyGtkFit (pygtk)
```